Showing a function is an immersion
Hey all I'm just looking for a second opinion about a problem from Lee's Manifolds book.
He leaves as an exercise to verify the map $X(u,v)=((\cos(2\pi u)+2)\cos(2\pi v), (\cos(2\pi u)+2)\sin(2\pi v), \sin(2\pi u))$ is an immersion. The differential is
$DX=\begin{bmatrix}-2\pi\sin(2\pi u)\cos(2\pi v) & -2\pi(\cos(2\pi u) + 2)\sin(2\pi v)\\-2\pi\sin(2\pi u)\sin(2\pi v)& 2\pi(\cos(2\pi u)+2)\cos(2\pi v)\\
2\pi\cos(2\pi u)&0
 \end{bmatrix}$
I'll spare the details of my computation but I tried using Gauss Jordan elimination on the differential to compute the kernel but that went... poorly and seemed to require some creative use of trig identities that I wasn't seeing.
Is there some trick I'm missing, or is this just an extremely tricky computation?

The cross product of the partials is non-vanishing....

It suffices to observe that if the two columns are linearly dependent, then $DX^3_1 = 2\pi\cos(2\pi u) = 0$. But under that assumption, the matrix simplifies into $$ \pm 2\pi\begin{bmatrix} -\cos(2\pi v) & -2\sin(2\pi v) \ -\sin(2\pi v) & 2\cos(2\pi v) \ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, $$ which is easily seen to have rank $2$.

Note that the columns of your derivative matrix are, in fact, orthogonal nonzero vectors. This makes them linearly independent.
